# Pop method removes random element instead of top element in Python?

Tags: python, set, stack, programming-languages

In Python when we use pop method to remove an element from set why does it remove any random element? Instead of removing top element as per the stack's nature.

Comment: Please add a working example that shows this.

Comment: Are you saying "I'm surprised that sets behave as though they're unordered, is this documented anywhere?", or are you saying "I understand that sets are unordered, but why did the language devs choose to implement them in this way?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a set is an *un-ordered* collection of items, by definition. There it no "first" or "last" element. So, it removes a random one. If you want order, use a list instead.